# Adding the WebView to NSPopover doesn't show the WebView, just the NSView

Tags: macos, swift, webview, nsview, nspopover

In the AppDelegate  init() I have

```
 popover = NSPopover()
 popover.behavior = .Transient
 popover.contentViewController = ContentViewController()
```

Now in the ContentViewController : NSViewController

```
 override func loadView() {

        view = NSView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: view, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 580))
        view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: view, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 425))

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(["UserAgent": "Tick Mac App"])
        let url = NSURL(string: tickExtensionURL )!
        var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)

        var webView = WebView(frame: view.bounds)
        webView.mainFrame.loadRequest(request)
        view.addSubview(webView)

    }
```

[image]

As you can see the view appears but not the WebView. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you have to tell the controller whats its view so add this at the end of load view

```
self.view = view
```